# Dell Poweredge 2970 - Cheap subsitute/compatible RAM for lab env?

Tags: memory, dell, dell-poweredge

I'm building a lab environment for virtualized routers, in prep for my next network cert. I have a Dell Poweredge 2970, but it only has 16G of RAM. I need to upgrade the RAM, to the max of 64GB, but the price for 8GB sticks is too killer to justify for self study.

Is there a functional consumer grade substitute?

The user manual states when all slots are populated with 8gb, it only runs at 533MHz, instead of the normal 667MHz. The specs show DDR2 PC2-5300. My google skills tell me no - this is not possible. However, I'm hoping there's a trick, or some other models that provides the functionality, without the "enterprise®" features. I just need the horsepower to run the VM(s).

Documentation that I referenced:

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/poweredge-2970/manuals

ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-2970_User%27s%20Guide4_en-us.pdf

Comment: It's PC2-5300R ECC. Registered + ECC is important. Actual bus speed doesn't matter too much if it is lower than the RAM spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need DDR2 registered ECC memory.  Any consumer type non-registered, non-ECC simply wont physically fit in the slot - the notch between groups of pins is in a different place.

If you dont care about warranty or support you dont have to use Dell branded modules - most memory manufacturer sites will let you pick your server and show you compatible RAM.  Or if you need it really cheap there is plenty on ebay.

Comment: [Looks like 8x8GB PC2-5300 ECC DIMM is gonna run you at least $500.](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=DDR2+PC2-5300+ecc&_from=R40%7CR40&_osacat=175698&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.XDDR2+PC2-5300+ecc+8x8gb&_nkw=DDR2+PC2-5300+ecc+8x8gb&_sacat=175698)

Comment: @DylanKnoll Note that there are some individual ones for cheaper - around $30 - so its worth looking for single 8Gb sticks as well.

Comment: Both are great points. @DylanKnoll Thank you for the additional link as well. The one's I had scoped were $400/per 8GB. Now that I know what I need, I'm seeing the price points I'm expecting. Thanks again.